# Expression web does not translate the php code

Tags: php, web

Hy!

I write a website with Expression web 4 developer environment. I use php srcipt inside the side. When I watch in the browser in my website. The php code is not translated. And does not work. I use xampp. The server is running. If I copy the website files to the localhost. And I open it in the browser that works.

How can I set it in the Expression Web? So If I run my website, that runs on the localhost

Answer (score 2):

There are two options to try. If you are using the internal development server to preview your site, you need to add the path to your php-cgi.exe executable. You do this by going to the Tools menu in Expression Web and clicking on Application Options. The path at the bottom of the General tab. The default path is at C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe

The other (and probably preferred) method is to create the site in Apache's folder (default is C:\xampp\htdocs). Then go into the Site menu in Expression Web and select Site Settings. Click on the Preview tab and at the bottom, click the radio button next to "Preview using custom URL for this website" and enter the path to your site. Of course, make sure the Apache service is running in the XAMPP Control Panel before previewing the site.

Hope this helps.